# Asp.Net Response class and Write Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, httpresponse

When I create a simple webform example, I write the below code to display data on a web page.

Response.Write("hello World");

Usual syntax in csharp is

Create an object like 
ClassName objectName = New ClassName()

And call the method like
objectName.MethodName();

for STatic Classes there is no object creation and we can call method like
ClassName.MethodName();

In this context

How does Response.Write() work?
I know that Write() is a method. My question is what is Response here.

**Is it a static class? or a Object(This should not be true)?**

I am trying to understand if it is a static class from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it is a sealed class. How is it possible to call a sealedClassName.MethodName()?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Response is a property of your class.And Response isn't static because you can refer it using the keyword this . For more details read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's an instance [property on the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.response%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and it is inherited from the base class (Page).

Comment: Is it like ClassName.PropertyName.MethodName()? 
Here className = Page, PropertyName = Response, MethodName=Write.

Comment: @Chandana That would be how you'd access an instance method of an object returned from a static property.  Here you're accessing an instance method on the object returned from an *instance* property, which you're getting from the current instance.